# RGB codes from text box

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textbox, rgb

(First of all I'm a noob cuz I just started studying c# 2 weeks ago)
I got an exercise from my teacher which is: Write a program to draw a star. Let the user determine R, G and B values via text boxes so your program is able to draw the star in any color!

I have this code and it draws a star, but I don't know how to get the numbers from the TextBoxes to replace the R, G and B.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Line myLine = new Line();
        myLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        myLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        myLine.X1 = 200;
        myLine.Y1 = 1;
        myLine.X2 = 80;
        myLine.Y2 = 350;
        caPaper.Children.Add(myLine);

        Line mLine = new Line();
        mLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        mLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        mLine.X1 = 200;
        mLine.Y1 = 1;
        mLine.X2 = 320;
        mLine.Y2 = 350;
        caPaper.Children.Add(mLine);

        Line vLine = new Line();
        vLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        vLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        vLine.X1 = 1;
        vLine.Y1 = 120;
        vLine.X2 = 320;
        vLine.Y2 = 350;
        caPaper.Children.Add(vLine);

        Line bLine = new Line();
        bLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        bLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        bLine.X1 = 399;
        bLine.Y1 = 120;
        bLine.X2 = 80;
        bLine.Y2 = 350;
        caPaper.Children.Add(bLine);

        Line nLine = new Line();
        nLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        nLine.StrokeThickness = 2;
        nLine.X1 = 1;
        nLine.Y1 = 120;
        nLine.X2 = 399;
        nLine.Y2 = 120;
        caPaper.Children.Add(nLine);


    }

    private void txtR_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtG_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txtB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `byte.Parse()` to parse numbers from textboxes:

```
Color.FromRgb( byte.Parse(txtR.Text), byte.Parse(txt.G.Text), byte.Parse(txtB.Text));
```

or even better:

```
   byte r = byte.Parse(txtR.Text),
   g = byte.Parse(txt.G.Text),
   b =  byte.Parse(txtB.Text);
```

do the above code one time at the begining of your method.

Comment: I feel like such a noob but I don't know where should i put this line. This does not work:             nLine.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(int.Parse(txtR.Text), int.Parse(txtG.Text), int.Parse(txtB.Text)));

Comment: put  int R = int.Parse(txtR.Text),
   G = int.Parse(txt.G.Text),
   B = int.Parse(txtB.Text);`  right after `Line myLine = new Line();` in your main window method method. and your program will work.

Comment: Am I still doing something wrong? Here is what i see: https://gyazo.com/2482ad4d59805d3888597a4be0a9f70b

Comment: Cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte'

Comment: @MinJie, oh so they are byte, i thought they were int, so look at my edited answer.

Comment: that error means you have a non numeric character in your text box (for example a letter, space, ...) if you enter just a numeric value between 0 and 255 it won't happen.

Comment: Oh it works if I write the numbers in before starting to run the programme but do I need to add a button to be able to write the numbers in the textboxes and change the color of the lines? Because now if i change the numbers and i press enter nothing happens :/

Comment: You just need a button to call your method when clicked, but add your code in the main window to a method and call it from main window, as you don't want `InitializeComponent();` every time, it has to be called once when application starts.